# What is the difference when we declare an array in C# and in C++?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[] arr = new int[3]; // C#
int arr[3]; //C++
```

Declaration of array in c++ will allocate  a block of memory for three integers.

I can assume the same with language c#, but because of the following facts I can't.

Every variable in c# is struct or class or enum, As Array is a class, arr should be the object of class Array.
Intellisense also shows that arr has many member functions same as of functions of class Array, but Array is an abstract class, as we can not instantiate an abstract class, arr can be the object of any other class which might be implementing Array Class

If my deduction is right, I want to know

1. Which class arr is an object of?

And if my deduction is wrong

1. I want to know where am I wrong?
2. Which Class array is an object of?

Comment: "Why the designers of c# go" - how should we know? Magic? Opinion based.

Comment: "Why designers of C# ..." - usually not answerable with concrete answer hence off-topic. My guess "Why designers of C# used syntax for array that is used by many other languages with C-like syntax?" Maybe because there are many other languages (C, C++, Java, JavaScript) that use similar syntax?

Comment: FYI your example isn't C++ array, it's C. C++ array example would be std::array<int, 3> arr = {1,2,3};

Comment: You're right `System.Array` is an `abstract class`. As hvd said in his answer, the concrete type which inherits from `System.Array` is in this case `System.Int32[]` or just `int[]`. There are reference conversions between `System.Array` and `int[]` in the same way as there is between any base class and inheriting class (reference type). As you say, instance members of `System.Array` are inherited to `int[]` (some are overridden). However, in some respects the class `int[]` is of a special nature. Also note that it implements closed generic interfaces like `IList<int>` and `IReadOnlyList<int>`.

Comment: The C++ version has stronger guarantees on where the array will be. You know for sure that in the C++ case, the array is on the stack and will be deterministically deallocated when you leave the calling function.

Comment: From your example : In C, things are as simple as possible : arr is a pointer to the first of three consecutive integers. In C#, arr is a reference (aka pointer) to something more complex, an object. That object itself contains (among other things) : a reference to the type (System.Int32[] here), the array itself (like in C) and some other useful properties like array length.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Considering how often at least one of the C# language designers browses this tag, it's not unanswerable at all. He can give you the exact reason they chose this.

Comment: The difference?  Everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hard to compare the two, they have very little in common.  C++ inherited this array syntax and behavior from the C language.  Which was designed with only one goal in mind, only as-fast-as-possible was ever considered.  The word "allocate" you use is already a poor mismatch with what happens at runtime, the int[3] syntax merely *reserves* space.  Exactly where that happens depends on the location of the declaration, inside a function it will reserve space on the stack frame, outside it will reserve space in the data section.

With no execution guarantees, the elements are not initialized, the runtime doesn't keep track of the size of the array, there is no index checking.  As fast as possible, features that otherwise launched billions of bugs and tens of thousands of malware attacks.  A buffer overflow is a standard problem in a C or C++ program, producing *very* hard to diagnose bugs when it corrupts memory, randomly overwriting other variables or the return address of a function.  Or commandeer a program simply with data, the malware attack vector.

Not the C# way of course.  Array types are reference types in the .NET Framework, their storage is always allocated from the GC heap.  The fast gen#0 heap if the array is small (less than 85KB), from the Large Object Heap otherwise.  There is lots and lots of glue in the jitter and the CLR to make them still as fast as possible, in spite of their guarantees:

- there is dedicated IL opcode to create an array, [Opcodes.NewArr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newarr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the jitter translates it to a direct call into the CLR.
- this helper function dynamically creates the array type if it doesn't exist yet (compare to [Type.MakeArrayType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makearraytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), allocates the storage from the GC heap and initializes the object, setting the Length property and initializing the array members so they all have their default(T) value.
- accessing the elements of the array in your code again produces dedicated IL opcodes, like [Opcodes.LdElem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The jitter translates them into machine code instructions that check the array bounds and accesses the array element.
- other array members produce direct calls to the internal SZArrayHelper class, optimized to produce fast-as-possible code for one-dimensional arrays.
- the code optimizer in the jitter looks for opportunities to eliminate the array bound checks, possible when it can see from the code that the index expression cannot be out-of-bounds.  This is often possible, particularly when you use foreach or write a for(;;) loop that uses the array's Length property, array access is then just as fast as the equivalent in C.
- the garbage collector has built-in knowledge of arrays, it rearranges array elements of a reference type when it compacts the heap so they can be sequentially accessed in code that iterates the array.  Very, *very* important on modern processors that depend on the CPU caches to make memory access fast.  This is where managed code can beat native C or C++ code handily, native memory allocations are stuck wherever they happen to exist.

C# still has syntax to emulate C arrays, without the safety guarantees.  You can use them when you found that the array code is in the critical path for your program.  These constructs require you to use the *unsafe* keyword, they have the same problems as the equivalent C code:

- the [stackalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx) keyword is available to allocate an array from the stack frame instead of the GC heap.  Just like a local array variable does in a C program.  It is a fallback when the local arrays in your C# code produce too much garbage and GC collections start to dominate your program's execution time.
- the [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) keyword is available to declare arrays that can be accessed without bounds checking.  The alternative for stackalloc for arrays that need to survive the method call.  It is a fallback when you can't get the index checking eliminated and the profiler tells you that it becomes critical.  This is generally only the case for short arrays, the kind where the element access isn't the dominant cost.

Addressing your questions with the above info in mind:

> Which class arr is an object of?

As you can tell from the 2nd bullet, an array has a dedicated type and it is created on the fly without you explicitly declaring it in your program.  The CLR otherwise maintains the illusion that it is a type strongly correlated to the element type, like the C# language syntax does, the name of the array type for an array of ints is "System.Int32[]".  It is however a distinct type in the CLR, a class that logically derives from System.Array and practically derives from System.SZArrayHelper.  My favorite phrase for such type shenanigans is "quacks like a duck-typing".

> Why the designers of c# go with the above syntax?

It is syntax sugar, pretty effective at being short and understandable.  It *might* have looked different if generics would have been available at .NET 1.0, I kind of doubt it.  Notable as well is that C# has a bit too much sugar for multi-dimensional arrays (like `int[,]`) and not enough for jagged arrays (like `int[][]`), they can lull a programmer into writing poorly performing code.  They are expensive, index expressions require multiple multiplications and bound checks and it is way too easy to access the array elements in an order that is very unfriendly to the CPU caches.

Comment: +1 for focusing on the two being very _different_ and the fact the guarantees are very different in C# and C++. I think this answer is much better than the other one by hvd.

Answer (score 10):

> Every variable in c# is struct or class or enum

Every variable in C# has a type, and that type is either a value type or a reference type. In some cases, all value types are classified as `struct`, and all reference types are classified as `class`, but that's not usual. If that is what you meant, then the "or enum" is redundant, because they are value types. If that's not what you meant, there are some cases you overlooked, such as interface types.

> Which class arr is an object of?

`arr` is an object of type `int[]`. `int[]` is a reference type which derives from `System.Array`, but it's a stretch to call it a class type unless you call all reference types class types.

> Why the designers of c# go with the above syntax, why did not they go with the simple ClassName ObjectName = new ClassName() with the arrays too

The "ClassName" is `int[]`, so your proposal would lead to `int[] arr = new int[](3);`. This is more verbose, does not look familiar to people coming to C# from other languages, and does not actually manage to simplify the language: the language *still* would need to have special rules for where `[` and `]` may be used.

Comment: Not really related: Were you aware that the order of `[]` brackets in nested arrays is different in C# and CLR? For example a two-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays of three-dimensional arrays of `int`s. Try `var clrName = typeof(int[,][][,,]).ToString();` to understand what I mean. If you make a five-dimensional array based on that, in CLR notation you append `[,,,,]` in the end (to the right), while in C# notation you insert the `[,,,,]` symbol between the `int` symbol and the already existing brackets (to the left).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I never really thought about it, but I guess that makes sense. C#'s `int[,][] arr;`'s elements are created as `new int[x,y][]` and accessed as `arr[x,y][z]`, so it's nice that C#'s order matches between the declaration and the use. CLR does not use that notation to access elements, so there's more incentive to use the simpler rule (to make a one-dimensional array type, append `[]`)

Comment: Then how will you explain array of objects of user-defined class (ClassName[] obj = new ClassName[3]). I would be grateful if you could provide any material to read about reference type int[].

Comment: @user3521181 If you change `int` to `ClassName` in my answer, it still makes sense. `obj` is an object of type `ClassName[]`, which is a reference type which derives from `System.Array`. The "ClassName" is `ClassName[]`, so your proposal would lead to `ClassName[] obj = new ClassName[](3);`. As for a reference, I don't think it's the easiest way, but it is the most reliable: inspect `typeof(int[])`'s properties in the Visual Studio debugger.