# Why are jagged arrays in C# defined in the opposite way?

Tags: c#, language-design

Let's say I have a type called `T`. Now let's say I make an array of type `T`, it gives me `T[]`. In code, it gives:

```
var myArray = new T[10];
```

With a length of 10. So, we can see that this makes an array that contains 10 items of type `T`. This works if `T` is `int`, `string`, `BinaryWriter` or anything standard. But let's say `T` is an *array* type, like `int[]` or `string[]`.

Then, if we want to define an array of 10 items of type `T` (`int[]`), it should give something like this:

```
var myArray = new int[][10];
```

By replacing `T` by `int[]` in the previous example. But this gives a syntax error, because the correct syntax in C# is:

```
var myArray = new int[10][];
```

Which, if we followed the logic of the first example, should give an array containing *an undefined amount* of arrays containing 10 integers.

The same applies for any dimension of jagged arrays:

```
var myArray = new int[][][10];
```

Is wrong because the syntactically correct way is:

```
var myArray = new int[10][][];
```

This isn't a personal preference or a code style debate, but simply logic: why is the syntax different when we define arrays of *array types*, than when we define arrays of anything else?

Comment: I've wondered this myself.  It seems horribly wrong.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://ericlippert.com/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/

Comment: using your syntax, that means you'd do `var myArray = new int[][10];` then `myArray[0] = new int[10]`. Doesn't look natural to me

Comment: I know C# is a *professional* language that was designed by people with experience in the field of language design, so I always thought there was some kind of reason behind that.

Comment: Isn't that even the reverse meaning of how it is defined in C?

Comment: @KevinGosse Why would I want to set the first item to be an `int[10]`? The only thing I want here is define *something* that can contains 10 items of type `int[]`. The length of the underlying items doesn't matter.

Comment: @MikeMB C does it the way C# does, but Java does it the way that OP expected.

Comment: The CLR has an opposite order. For example, with `var arr = new T[5, 20][][,,,][,,];`, in C# syntax the type is called `T[,][][,,,][,,]`, but `arr.GetType().ToString()` will give `"T[,,][,,,][][,]"`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104141/what-is-the-difference-when-we-declare-an-array-in-c-sharp-and-in-c. Fact is, your question is opinion based. Even one of the actual language designers will simply express their opinion that led to the design, and the rest of us can _only_ opine about _their_ opinion. That said, the syntax they chose ensures that indexes wind up in the same lexical order when writing the code, which makes sense to me, even if it doesn't seem consistent with respect to the `<array type>[]` pattern.

Comment: @sepp2k: Right, sorry I mixed that up. Then I think the answer is clear: They wanted to keep the syntax as similar to C as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way, the initialization syntax mirrors the access syntax.

```
var myArray = new int[NUM_ROWS][];
...
/* Initialize rows of myArray */
...
var x = myArray[0][5]; /* Should this be row 0, col 5; or row 5, col 0? */
```

It would be counterintuitive for `myArray[0][5]` to be parsed as `(myArray[5])[0]` since the indices would be inverted left-to-right, so we instead have `myArray[0][5]` parsed as `(myArray[0])[5]`.

As such, in `myArray[i][j]`, `i` corresponds to the index into the two-dimensional array, and `j` corresponds to the index into the one-dimensional array `myArray[i]`.

Now, `i` can range from `0` to `NUM_ROWS-1`, so it is symmetrical with the access syntax to initialize `var myArray = new int[NUM_ROWS][]`. This way, the left set of brackets still corresponds to the length of the two-dimensional array, and the right set of brackets still corresponds to the one-dimensional array.

**Edit:** I see someone posted in the comments [a link to an article where Eric Lippert goes through a more elaborate example and justification](https://ericlippert.com/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/).

Comment: seems logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

`new T[10]` says you want an array of 10 items of type T.  It is not the same as `new int[][10]` because it does not behave like a preprocessor macro in other languages.  It doesn't just swap T with whatever the type is to create `new int[][10]`.  Instead it is being consistent with the fact that T is always the inner type and `new T[10]` defines the size of the outer array.

So if T was DateTime then you'd expect to have 10 date times and access them such as `myArray[9].Day`

If each item T is an `int[]` then you'd still always index into the array of 10 items and then access the item T, which is an array: `myarray[9][2465]` assuming the inner array at index 9 had at least 2466 items.

So the index of the outer array always comes first.

A `T[10]` is a size 10 array of items T.  Whatever T is the inner item.

You state your expectation is that `new T[10]` would produce  `var myArray = new int[][10];`.  However even in C++ when declaring a multidimensional array, the outer dimension comes first in the declaration:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Declaring a jagged array is similar in C++ except you must use pointer syntax and first declare the outer array then initialize each inner array separately.

Let's think about it in terms of the semantics of what each statement is saying:

A) `new T[10]`: I want an array of outer dimension 10, with each element containing a type T

B) `new T[10]` where `T` is `int[]`: I want an array of outer dimension 10, with each element containing an int array of unknown length.

C) `new int[][10]`: I want an array of outer dimension unknown, with each element containing an array of 10 integers.

D) `new int[10][]`: I want an array of outer dimension 10, with each element containing an int array of unknown length.

Notice that B and D match, but B and C do not match.